# Old version of Wordpress on new PHP. Error reporting

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

I am working on an old site and it is an old version of Wordpress. I am getting deprecated errors everywhere :(

I have put

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

under where the original code sets the reporting so to over-ride it but I am still getting errors. Even from the same document below where I have entered the above code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it's an idea to fix the errors?

Comment: Or upgrade that version of Wordpress?

Comment: I can imagine fixing the errors will open a can of worms and I am unable to upgrade the Wordpress version.

Comment: @beingalex: There are specialized wordpress programmers that start to monitor the warnings you get and take care to fix the codebase of wordpress you're using w/o opening a can of worms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@maiorano84 It's not always possible to just simply upgrade Wordpress depending on the hosting company - as some are still running MySQL 4 or lower. Whereas Wordpress 3.2 upwards requires MySQL 5.

As for the original question, try setting display_errors to off also.

```
 display_errors = Off
```

Comment: If a hosting company is running MySQL 4 or lower, then maybe it's a good idea to upgrade Wordpress AND switch hosting companies. There is absolutely no excuse for any hosting company to not stay up to date, as the security risks are enormous. As mentioned earlier, maybe it's a better idea to FIX the errors, rather than hide them and hope they go away.

Comment: Oh, I agree completely. But there are companies that are still running old versions. 3IX.org are running 4.1.2.2 and have no plans to upgrade either. Bizarre!